# How to define a formula in FormulaData?

Tags: version-10, core-language

I am looking for a way to manage frequently used formulas in my research, in a organized way in Mathematica.

It appears to me that using `FormulaData` would be a standard way to use formulas in Mathematica. Is there a way to define formulas ourselves in `FormulaData`?

Answer (score 3):

You could, for example, do the following:

Find all inbuilt formulas

```
formulas = FormulaLookup[All];
```

There are 1066 formulas. We only want to see those including "speed" somewhere

```
(speed =
   Union @ Flatten[
     StringCases[#, ___ ~~ "speed" ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True] & /@
      formulas]) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Extract those with FormulaData

```
(inter = Intersection[FormulaData[], speed]) // Multicolumn
```

[image]

Define "MySpeed"

```
myspeed =
  List["MySpeed",
    Equal[QuantityVariable["ms", "Page"], 
      Times[QuantityVariable["ppt", "PageRate"], 
        QuantityVariable["M", "Time"]]]]
```

> {MySpeed, ms == M ppt}

Prepend "MySpeed"

```
table = Join[{myspeed}, {#, FormulaData[#]} & /@ inter];

TraditionalForm@Framed[
  Grid[table,
   Dividers -> All,
   Spacings -> {{2, 2}, 3},
   Alignment -> Left, BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
   Background -> {None, {{Hue[.6, .15, .9], GrayLevel[.9]}}},
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thick, White]],
  FrameMargins -> 0.5, FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[.7]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, I would be more interested in the possibility that the formula is added into `FormulaData` (so that I can use something like `FormulaData["MySpeed", {"M"->1}]` or `FormulaLookup["MySpeed"]`), instead of being able to list the equation together with the other ones :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<<FormulaData`
Needs@"GeneralUtilities`"

GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected[{Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`MathematicaFormula},
    Tools`MathematicaFormulas`FormulaData`Private`MathematicaFormula["MyFormula"] := QuantityVariable["a","ElectricPotential"] == QuantityVariable["b","ElectricPotential"]
]

FormulaData["MyFormula"]
FormulaData["MyFormula", {"b" -> 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works for simple formulas. But I'd like to add formulas that involve integrals and unspecified functions. I know I can declare a general variable with `QuantityVariable["K", "MultiplicativeConstants"]`. But how do I do this with a general function? Could you give an example, where the formula is
`Inactive[Integrate][f[x] g'[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] == 1` with `f` and `g` unspecified?

Comment: @JEM_Mosig There's no such example in built-in formulae. Maybe we should just use a symbol `f` and `ReplaceAll`.